# how to get the position of an active window?

Tags: python-3.x, xlib

I try to  get the position of an active window with code below.

```
from Xlib import display, X

d = display.Display()
screen = d.screen()

root = screen.root

active_window_id = root.get_full_property(
    d.intern_atom('_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW'), X.AnyPropertyType
).value[0]

print(hex(active_window_id))

active_window = d.create_resource_object('window', active_window_id)

geometry = active_window.get_geometry()
x = geometry.x
y = geometry.y

print("window position:", x, y)

d.close()
```

but whenever i move the active window(terminal) , it print the same position.

who can tell me why,and the true code;

Comment: If your window is managed by a window manager and has decorations, then your window is most likely a child of another window and you always will get the same coordinates, no matter where the parent window is positioned on the screen. Therefore, one has to translate the coordinates of the client window to the coordinate space of the root window (client_to_screen), see: [XTranslateCoordinates](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XTranslateCoordinates.html).

Answer (score 0):

i got it though these code:

```
from Xlib import X, XK, display
import Xlib.Xatom

def get_active_win_geometry():
    """
    Returns the (x, y, height, width) of a window relative to the top-left
        of the screen.
    """
    local_dpy = display.Display()
    root = local_dpy.screen().root
    active_window_id = root.get_full_property(
        local_dpy.intern_atom('_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW'), X.AnyPropertyType
    ).value[0]
    win = local_dpy.create_resource_object('window', active_window_id)
    geom = win.get_geometry()
    pos = geom.root.translate_coords(win.id, 0, 0)

    (x, y) = (pos.x, pos.y)
    return (x, y, geom.width, geom.height)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).